# How to trigger JavaScript custom events correctly

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dispatchevent, custom-events

I am struggling to understand how a custom event type is linked to a specific user action/trigger. All documentation seems to dispatch the event without any user interaction.

In the following example I want the event to be dispatched once a user has been hovering on the element for 3 seconds.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');img.src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
document.body.appendChild(img)
var event = new CustomEvent("hoveredforthreeseconds");

img.addEventListener('hoveredforthreeseconds', function(e) { console.log(e.type)}, true);


var thetrigger = function (element, event) {
    var timeout = null;
    element.addEventListener('mouseover',function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(element.dispatchEvent(event), 3000);
    },true);
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    },true);
};
```

I have a trigger but no logical way of connecting it to the event.

I was thinking about creating an object called `CustomEventTrigger` which is essentially `CustomEvent` but has a third parameter for the trigger and also creating a method called `addCustomEventListener`, which works the same as `addEventListener` but when initialised it then passes the target Element to the custom event trigger which then dispatches the event when it's instructed to.

Answer (score 2):

Custom events have to be triggered programatically through `dispatchEvent`, they are not fired by the DOM. You will always need to explictly call them in your code, such as in response to a user-generated event such as `onmouseover`, or a change of state such as `onload`.

You're very close to a working implementation, however you're immediately invoking `dispatchEvent` in your `setTimeout`. If you save it into a closure (as below) you can invoke `dispatchEvent` while passing your element after `setTimeout` has finished the timeout.

It's also good practice to declare your variables at the top of a file, to avoid possible scope issues.

```
var img = document.createElement('img'), timeout, event, thetrigger;

img.src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
document.body.appendChild(img);

img.addEventListener("hoveredForThreeSeconds", afterHover, false);

thetrigger = function (element, event) {
    timeout = null;
    element.addEventListener('mouseover',function() {
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){ element.dispatchEvent(event) }, 3000);
    },true);
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    },true);
};

function afterHover(e) {
    console.log("Event is called: " + e.type);
}

event = new CustomEvent("hoveredForThreeSeconds");

thetrigger(img, event);
```

Comment: thanks, but i was hoping not too trigger every event manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a method called `addCustomEventListener`, which works the same as `addEventListener` but when initialised passes the target Element to the custom event trigger which dispatches the event when it says, so in this case it only dispatches if the timeout reaches 3 seconds.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');

window.mouseover3000 = new CustomEvent('mouseover3000', {
  detail: {
    trigger: function(element, type) {
      timeout = null;
      element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          element.dispatchEvent(window[type])
        }, 3000);
      }, false);
      element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }, false)
    }
  }
});

window.tripleclick = new CustomEvent('tripleclick', {
  detail: {
    trigger: function(element, type) {
      element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(e.detail ===3){
          element.dispatchEvent(window[type])
        }    
      }, false);
    }
  }
});
EventTarget.prototype.addCustomEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture, wantsUntrusted) {

  this.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, wantsUntrusted);
  window[type].detail.trigger(this, type);
}

var eventTypeImage = function(e) {
  this.src = "http://placehold.it/200x200?text=" + e.type;
}

img.addEventListener('mouseout', eventTypeImage, false);
img.addEventListener('mouseover', eventTypeImage, false);
img.addCustomEventListener('mouseover3000', eventTypeImage, false);
img.addCustomEventListener('tripleclick', eventTypeImage, false);
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://placehold.it/200x200?text=No+hover" ;/>
```

I think this could be useful to others so please feel free to improve on this.